# Dual boot no ubuntu option

Tags: dual-boot

So recently I installed Ubuntu along side my already installed Windows 7.
I installed Ubuntu on a unallocated volume which I shrinked from my main volume.
Now on boot up I get no boot up option for Ubuntu.PC just boot straight to Windows. 
Can someone please explain how I can get the dual boot to go to Ubuntu

Also with the Ubuntu installation, it didn't detect any operating systems (but I have Windows installed just not on the same volume partition).So I took the "Something else" install type option and just installed Ubuntu on the unallocated free space (which I prepared before hand).Only problem now is no boot up option for Ubuntu .Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Appears like GRUBx.x (LINUX bootloader) hasn't been installed while the installation and that is why, windows bootloader (the default bootloader) automatically boots-up as your system starts.

To install Linux Bootloader, follow the instructions provided in the link below and you'll probably be able to dual boot your system:

http://buff.ly/1rS678D.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Linux using the Ubuntu install live-CD (or USB) then open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda? /mnt (replace sda? with the partition where you installed the root fs, use gparted if you don't know)
sudo chroot /mnt
#if you have a separate boot partition: mount /boot
mount /dev
mount /proc
mount /sys
update-grub 
grub-install /dev/sda
```

If there are no error, you can restart and it should work.